# 2 errors compiling clang and llvm with Visual C++ 2015 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm

There are 2 errors:

1.) C2039 in project clangCodeGen in file BackendUtil.cpp on line 574, "MCIncrementalLinkerCompatible" is not a member of "llvm::MCTargetOptions".

2.) C2660 in project clang in file cc1as_main.cpp on line 404, cannot use 9 arguments for the function "llvm::Target::createMCObjectStreamer".

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes. How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Do you have code showing line 574 and line 404?  I don't see any errors on those lines, because .... there isn't any code posted!

Comment: What version of the source are you compiling? `createMCObjectStreamer`  looks like it should take 9 arguments; how is it declared in the headers you have?

Comment: Here is line 574:

    Options.MCOptions.MCIncrementalLinkerCompatible =
      CodeGenOpts.IncrementalLinkerCompatible;

Here is line 404:

    Str.reset(TheTarget->createMCObjectStreamer(
        T, Ctx, *MAB, *Out, CE, *STI, Opts.RelaxAll,
        Opts.IncrementalLinkerCompatible,
        /*DWARFMustBeAtTheEnd*/ true));

Comment: It's version 3.7.0 of LLVM. I don't know the clang version. I downloaded both via Subversion a few days ago.

Here is the prototype for createMCObjectStreamer:

  MCStreamer *createMCObjectStreamer(const Triple &T, MCContext &Ctx,
                                     MCAsmBackend &TAB, raw_pwrite_stream &OS,
                                     MCCodeEmitter *Emitter,
                                     const MCSubtargetInfo &STI, bool RelaxAll,
                                     bool DWARFMustBeAtTheEnd) const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your version of clang is not compatible with your version of LLVM.

The `IncrementalLinkerCompatible` flag causing your problem was only added to LLVM four days ago (http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.cvs/292184).

So I think you must have downloaded the current version of it rather than 3.7.0.

Comment: This is strange because I got them both through the trunk. I tried downloading it from clang.llvm.org, but cmake won't work due to missing header files (like dirent.h and dlfcn.h), even though a large number of them are in my MingW include directory, and that include directory has been added to the PATH environmental variable. The header files worked with the trunk versions, but the website-downloaded ones seem to prevent cmake from seeing the MingW include directory.